# Why are my boxes only existing for one frame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make it so that once I press the f key, a box is permanently created. However, once the f key is pressed, the box only exists for one frame. How can I create a permanent box that is triggered by a key press? Thanks.

Here is an excerpt from the code that I created and has the problems described above:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    
        if event.key == pygame.K_f:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,0), (200, 200, 15, 15))
```

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and give us a *complete* example of the code. Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event occurs only once when the button is pressed. Therefore the box is just visible for 1 frame. If you want to make the box permanent, you need to draw it in the application loop.

Add a state variable `draw_box` and set the state when the button is pressed. Draw the box depending on the state of `draw_box`:

```py
draw_box = False

# application loop
run = True 
while run:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False   

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                draw_box = True       
        

    # [...]

    if draw_box: 
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), (200, 200, 15, 15))

    # [...]

    pygame.display.update()
```